# Django client test (get, post) response load data from main db instead fixtures loaded in test db

Tags: python, django, testing, fixtures

I'm new in Django, and I have this problem:
I use self.client to test routes in my app.
e.g.

```
class BookSell(TestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'sellers.yaml',
        'books.yaml'
          ...
    ]

    def test_get_book_sell(self):
        book = Books.objects.get(pk=1)
        print(book.name)#it prints "El Quijote" in the test output
        response = self.client.get('/sell/book-sell')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "Book Sell")
        self.assertContains(response, "El Quijote")#book name
```

The view method linked to that path should load some data from the database and then render it. 
But when I run

```
python manage.py test app_name
```

it doesn't load data from fixtures, because the response doesn't contain "El Quijote". Only when I run:

```
python manage.py loaddata fixture_name.yaml ...
```

and then run again the tests the view method loads data from the database.

So I conclude that when I run the tests, my views methods load data from main database instead of test database

What is that I'm doing wrong?
Is there a way to load just data from test database?

django version: 1.9.4

python version: 2.7.6

I'm sure that the fixtures load with sucess in test database

Comment: So the response does contain "El Quijote" when you run the test after you've run loaddata? The test database should always be completely separate from the real database, so that's a bit concerning.

Comment: yes my friend, I'm worried about it :c

Comment: I would try modifying your main database so that it is different from the fixtures (like, change the name of "El Quijote", then print all the book names in your test to see if the change carried over to the test database.

Comment: I did that, with `book = Books.objects.get(pk=1)` I get the name from fixture (test_database, "El Quijote").
In the response, I get the book name from the main DB, "El Quijote Main"

Comment: Try setting up a new Client instance explicitly in your TestCase.
    `def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()` Could be your TestCase is somehow getting ahold of an external client.

Comment: I tried that, and I get the same :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered what I was doing wrong, thanks to this answer: [Django: reload form data after db values change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773665/django-reload-form-data-after-db-values-change)

I had a form like this:

```
class BookSellForm(forms.Form):

    books = [('', 'Choose a book')]
    books.extend(Books.objects.values_list('id', 'name'))
    libro = forms.ChoiceField(books)
```

And that was the problem, I had to change to this

```
class BookSellForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookSellForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        books = [('', 'Choose a book')]
        books.extend(Books.objects.values_list('id', 'name'))
        self.fields['book'] = forms.ChoiceField(books)
```

and then everything worked fine, I hope this will be helpful to someone in the future.